# Logo does not dwindle on Mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a html web site on [here](https://serbay.net/demo/uzer.com.tr). Everything is fine on pc but when I browse the website on my phone the logo, slider texts and slider buttons do not dwindle. Here is the code of slider:

```
<div class="fullwidthbanner-container">
    <div class="fullwidthbanner">
        <ul>
            <li data-fstransition="fade" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="10" data-masterspeed="300">
                <img src="images/slider-02.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption text sfb" data-x="0" data-y="170" data-speed="400" data-start="800"  data-easing="easeOutExpo"><h2>AYDINLATMA ÜRÜNLERİMİZ</h2></div>
                <div class="caption text sfb" data-x="1" data-y="210" data-speed="400" data-start="1000" data-easing="easeOutExpo"><h3>AZ ENERJİ TÜKETEN ETKİLİ LAMBALAR</h3></div>
                <div class="caption text sfb" data-x="1" data-y="266" data-speed="400" data-start="1200" data-easing="easeOutExpo"><p>Çok daha az enerji ile daha etkili, zararsız ve <br/>ışık kirliliğine sebep olmayan lambalar.</p></div>
                <div class="caption sfb" data-x="650" data-y="170" data-speed="600" data-start="1300" data-easing="easeOutExpo"><img src="images/perdeli-isik.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="caption sfb" data-x="900" data-y="71" data-speed="600" data-start="1200" data-easing="easeOutExpo"><img src="images/lamba.png" alt=""></div>
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fullwidthbanner-container{
    max-width:1000px
    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 470px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image:url(../images/loader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logo and slider content dont't have CSS to style them on smaller screens.

For logo fix is simple. You can change `#logo a img` `height` to: `65px;` (style.css - about line 39), and `#header #logo` `margin-top` to `5px;` (style.css - about line 257).

To fix slider you need to rebuild it in mobile view - there's too much content to display it in such a small box. As a fast and easy solution you can hide it on mobile devices. 
To do it in style.css, right after media query `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {` (line 238) add:

```
.fullwidthbanner-container {
    display: none;
}
```

Of course you can manage `font-size` on mobile if you think it's enough. To do it just change font-size in style.css - line 3992

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {

.caption h2 {font-size: 15px; margin-top: 0;}
.caption h3 {font-size: 18px; margin-top: 10px;}
.caption p {display: none}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Logo problem is solved but slider is important for mobile also, so I can not hide slider. Is there any other solution to get smaller text in slider when it is on mobile?

Comment: Thank you a lot. This solves all my problem. Thank you again.